# making select query by entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

hey guys i have a problem i hope you can help me through it im working on making select query by entity and i need to make a select by the id in url like  ?reqid=2

this is the code i made trying to fix the problem but it gives this message :
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

```
string a = Request.QueryString["reqid"].ToString(); 

MasterPackEntities obj = new MasterPackEntities();
var ds = obj.news.Where(x => x.id == Convert.ToInt32(a)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this error because `LINQ to Entities` tries to translate `Convert.ToInt32` as a SQL statement, which fails. You can do it like this :

```
int a = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["reqid"].ToString()); 

MasterPackEntities obj = new MasterPackEntities();
var ds = obj.news.Where(x => x.id == a).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Do the conversion *outside* of the query, since the conversion cannot be understood by the query provider:

```
//consider using `TryParse` to handle invalid input
int a = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["reqid"].ToString());

MasterPackEntities obj = new MasterPackEntities();
var ds = obj.news.Where(x => x.id == a).ToList();
```